# Tools for a HTML-CSS simple website with full control

Tags: web-development, text-editor

I want to code an HTML website with simple text editor and tools (I'm not a professional).

**Why:**
I want to have full control, light and portable product and readable code and I don't want to learn how to use web development software or to depend upon any special technology.

**Objective:**
I need a website for an NGO to share some general info and PDF documents, allow users to fill a form, and, may be, other simple things. I do like to have a nice and simple graphical appearance but, almost, without animation.

On Ubuntu, I could use (for example) KWrite editor. Learn HTML5, CSS (for the menu) and, may be, Java-Script. I would add the hypertext links manually and use Firefox for testing. Is it enough for doing a good, compatible (browsers and devices) and stable product? Do you think that some professionals use the same way? Are there some high-level "functions"/"routines" that could be called by line code?

What would you suggest as (free) simple text editor (with text coloring, some shortcuts) for windows and for Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 for your coding (code highlighting and completion plus more plugins you'll ever need).

Prepros to run a local web-server and view what your building (supports live updating etc.).

Comment: Does this way allow to build enough stuffs with browsers' and devices' compatibility?

Comment: What you build, and it's browser / device compatibility is down to your code - not the text editor your using. KWrite, Sublime Text, Notepad - it's all just text saved in the right format.